# Overleaf raises errors in lines that do not contain them

Tags: errors, overleaf

I'm currently writing a project and encountered this bug (?).

Weird thing nº 1: LaTeX is raising errors in very basic commands, where there should be no errors. This is exclusive to this file, I've checked other files that also use commands like `\begin{enumerate}`, etc. and no error occur.

Weird thing nº 2: The errors don't actually seem to come from the code. As you can see in the example pictures, there are 2 errors in lines 58 and 60, that (apparently) refer to the `\newcommand` command and the `\center` command. But if we move those commands one line down, by creating an empty line above; the errors remain in lines 58 and 60, even though there is different stuff in them now.

#### Before

[image: before picture]

#### After

[image: after picture]

Comment: don't show only screenshots, show also the real error from the log.

Comment: If you are having trouble creating a reproducible example here or if you think that this is actually Overleaf-specific, please consider getting in touch with the Overleaf support team: support@overleaf.com.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If the file compiles fine, these "errors" are just warnings from the Overleaf editor that pre-parses the code and thinks that there is something wrong with it. This does not necessarily have to be true. If TeX issues no erroes upon compilation, you can just ignore these warnings. Look what the warning says, it should already give you a feeling whether these warnings are real errors or not.

Comment: there are actually 11 errors from only these 2 lines. In line 58:  6 "undefined control sequences" and 1 "missing number, treated as 0"; and from line 60: 4 "LaTeX Error: Unicode character β (U+03B2)"

Comment: If indeed TeX issues errors, we can only help you if you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). It is impossible to help you without the code that produces this. Typically, you should first try to address the first error TeX issues.

Comment: I does compile fine as far as I can tell, so I was inclined to ignore it in the first place. Glad to know this is not a problem.

Comment: Note that there may be warnings issued by the editor which you can sometimes ignore if the file compiles without errors. What you described in your questions looked more like warnings issued by the editor to me, which is why I added my prior comment. But what you describe now are indeed TeX errors. And these errors you should actually *not* ignore! If TeX issues errors, it does not compile fine (even if the output looks more or less right).

Comment: The full message from the log would show which file has the error. It may be an aux file, editors can get confused. Never ignore errors, the pdf is not intended to be usable after an error

Comment: one of your error circles is on `\center` which should never appear in a document use `\centering` or `\begin{center}..\end{center}`